# WCF - Informing about the progress to client (Can I use one-way call back methods within a request/reply operation)

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

My contract has request-reply operation which performs multiple tasks. So I would like to inform about the progress of the operation to the client as its a long running operation. So Duplex is the ideal choice as I can use call back methods. But my operation returns results at the end of the operations. So what is the recommendation to solve this problem?

1. Reuest-reply operation and one-way call back method for the  progress messaages from the service within the operation?
2. Blocking (request-reply) operation and blocking (sync) progress messages from service
3. Will the call back method uses same channel, so will my blocking (request-reply) method assumes its its result?

   - If yes, should I perform my service operation asynchronously.
4. Will the call back method will come in another worker thread or will be returned to the same thread which has given the instance context?

I think blocking service operation and blocking call back method for progress message (if it can return on another thread) will be ideal and easy solution.

But I am not sure how much WCF provides me out of box.

---

In Other words I want to do something similar to the below code(psuedo). Its working. Do you see any issues with this approach? (The idea is to calling a callback method within a blocking call. Service runs in multiple concurencymode. So i declared callback UseSynchronizationContext = false) to avoid deadlock.any issues are there with the below approach?

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract(typeof(IServiceCallback)]]
public interfact IService
{
     //A long (timetaken) request-reply operation
     string LonggggWork();
}

public interface IServiceCallback
{
     void Report(string msg);
}

[CallbackBehavior(ConcuerencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
public ClientCallback : IServiceCallback
{
public void Report(string msg)
{
     Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
}
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurencyMode.Multiple, InstanceMode.PerSession)]
publci Service : IService
{
     IServiceCallback callback = ....;
     public string LongggWork()
     {
          callback.Report("task1");
          task1();
          callback.Report("task2");
          task2();
           ...
               ...
     }
}
```

---

Eventhough if i set it UseSynchronizationContext to true, WCF is invoking the report method in worker thread itself. So looks like I dont need to set it to false. Will it make sense only for UI thread becasue I am invoking operation already in a another thread?

Answer (score 1):

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISubscriber))]
public interface IJobProcessor
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ProcessJob();
}



[ServiceContract]
public interface ISubscriber
{
    //This would be the operation using which the server would notify the client about the status.
    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateStatus(string statusMessage);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(JobProcessor), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:10000") });
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IJobProcessor), new NetTcpBinding(), "jobprocessor");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Server  running. Press enter to quit!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class JobProcessor : IJobProcessor
{
    public void ProcessJob()
    {
        ISubscriber subscriber = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISubscriber>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
            subscriber.UpdateStatus(String.Format("{0} % complete", (i + 1) * 20));
        }

    }
}
```

//Client would look something like this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proxy = DuplexChannelFactory<IJobProcessor>.CreateChannel(new InstanceContext(new Subscriber()), new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:10000/jobprocessor"));
        proxy.ProcessJob();
        Console.Write("Client proceeding with other work...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Subscriber : ISubscriber
{
    public void UpdateStatus(string statusMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(statusMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prasanth. But the challenge is calling the callback method within a request-reply operation and returning result in the end. And the service runs in persession instance mode and with multiple concurency. So I declared callback instacne as UseSynchronizationContext = false, so that it doesnt use the same thread as the caller. And I also declared concurency mode to multiple for effective throughput. Do you see any issues with this?

Comment: So when your client makes a call to the long running operation, it is ok if the calling thread gets blocked as long as the status of the operation is getting reported to the client? That is how the above code would behave, if I am not wrong. If that is your intention, the code looks fine to me :)

Comment: @Prasanth, IJobProcessor defines oneway operation. And survice uses the callback to update the client. But my servuce has request-reply (sync-twoway) operations. While performing those I want to give progress message. Here the service is re-entrant. i.e; at any given time only one thread will perform operations. Whereas my service is running with concurency mode as multiple as want good throughput becuase my operations takes long time.

Comment: Now I get it :) Your code seems fine to me and I do not anticipate any issues. That said, lets see if other people on stack overflow can come up with better answers :)